# Return particular key first when iterating over hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

I am iterating over a nested hash which is storing the versions of an object as the users have edited it over time. In this instance, the object represent trade offers, and both members of the trade have a copy of the trade which share a unique key linking them together. Whenever either makes a change to their trade offer, both user's trades are pushed into a hash with a hash key corresponding to their user_id, then both of those hashes are pushed into a hash with a key of the date the change was made, then finally all date hashes are stored in a master hash. It looks something like this:

```
history_hash = {
  "2018-03-22" => {
    "97" => {
      "id" => "2",
      "Offer" => "X Y, but no Z",
      "key" => "AZ81N3"
    },
    "242" => {
      "id" => "1",
      "Offer" => "X Y Z",
      "key" => "AZ81N3"
      }
    },

  "2018-03-15" => {
    "242" => {
      "id" => "1",
      "Offer" => "X Y Z",
      "key" => "AZ81N3"
      },
    "97" => {
      "id" => "2",
      "Offer" => "nil",
      "key" => "AZ81N3"
    }
  }   
}
```

TradeLog table is something like this:

```
id |    history   |    key
------------------------------
 1 | history_hash |  "AZ81N3"
```

On my show page, I have two sections: one iterates the actual trade objects belonging to the two users, the second I would like to be able to click on a date and see the trade versions per that date.

The problem is, the history_hash changes up the order in which the user_id's trade histories are saved. I would like to consistently display the version made by the currently logged in user on the left, and the other trade member's version on the right without simply hard-coding it in (I'd like to be able to expand the logic for three-party trades if possible).

Is there a way that I can change the hash.each loop to return a certain key value pair before the others depending on some input I give? Here's my current hash to display the information but the current user's information is flipped between being displayed on the left and right columns.

```
    <div>
      <h4>See previous versions of traid offer:</h4>
      <ul>
        <% @traid_logs.history.each do |date, user_traid| %>
          <li>
            <div class="columns">
              <div class="column">
                <p><%= date.to_date.to_s %></p>
                <div class="columns">

                  <% user_traid.each do |user_id, traid_log| %>
                    <div class="column">
                      <%= render "traid_logs/traid_log_information", traid_log: traid_log %>
                    </div>
                  <% end %>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried an `OrderedHash`? It preserves the order of the keys

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question. But, assuming `@traid_logs.history` returns:

```
{
  "2018-03-22" => {
    "97" => {
      "id" => "2",
      "Offer" => "X Y, but no Z",
      "key" => "AZ81N3"
    },
    "242" => {
      "id" => "1",
      "Offer" => "X Y Z",
      "key" => "AZ81N3"
      }
    },

  "2018-03-15" => {
    "242" => {
      "id" => "1",
      "Offer" => "X Y Z",
      "key" => "AZ81N3"
      },
    "97" => {
      "id" => "2",
      "Offer" => "nil",
      "key" => "AZ81N3"
    }
  }   
}
```

And:

```
@history_dates = @traid_logs.history.keys.sort{|a,b| b <=> a}
```

(Just to make sure you really have things in reverse chronological order.)

And:

```
@user_ids = ["97", "242"]
```

(Assuming "97" is the current user and "242" is the other user.)

I believe you could do something like:

```
<div>
  <h4>See previous versions of traid offer:</h4>
  <ul>
    <% @history_dates.each do |date| %>
      <li>
        <div class="columns">
          <div class="column">
            <p><%= date.to_date.to_s %></p>
            <div class="columns">

              <% @user_ids.each do |user_id| %>
                <div class="column">
                  <%= render "traid_logs/traid_log_information", traid_log: @traid_logs.history[date][user_id] %>
                </div>
              <% end %>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```